# Differential inclusion has unique solution

Tags: differential, subgradient

Given $f: X \to  \mathbb{R}$ a strict convex, lower semi-con. function with $X$ reflexive.

Show that the inclusion

$$l \in\partial f(x) \mbox{ (subgradient of f)}$$

posses an unique solution for every $l\in X^*$, under the assumption $\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|} \to \infty$.

My Idea is to show that the minimizer of $f(x)-l(x)$ is the unique solution. But is that possible?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: okay, thanks. Is there a good way to derive that?$ f-l$ has a minimizer because its convex again, I think. But why is the minimizer always in the subgradient?, (probably because of the coercive relation)?

Comment: Are you asking why $0 \in \partial f(x)$ if $f$ has a minimiser at $x$?

Comment: not quiet, actually why we dont have to look at  $0 \in \partial ( f(x)-l(x))$ in your answer you said...just deal with showing that $0 \in \partial f(x)$

Comment: I'll elaborate when I am at a keyboard.

Comment: take your time. ;) Thank you! btw.

Comment: I added a line to the second paragraph, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l \in X^*$, then we see that $f-l$ is strictly convex, lsc. and
$\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} {f(x)-l(x) \over \|x\|}= \infty$.

If we let $\phi= f -l$ we see that since $\partial \phi(x) = \partial f(x) - \{l\}$, then
$0 \in \partial \phi(x)$ **iff** $l \in \partial f(x)$.
Hence we can just deal with showing that $0 \in \partial f(x)$ for a
unique $x$.

Consider $L_\alpha = \{x | f(x) \le \alpha \}$.  Let $\alpha_n = { 1\over n}+\inf f$, then $L_{\alpha_n}$ are nested, non empty
weakly compact sets (since $X$ is reflexive). Hence
$L=\cap_n L_{\alpha_n}$ is non empty and hence $f$ has a minimiser, so
we have $0 \in \partial f(x)$ for some $x \in L$.

Now suppose $x,y $ are such that $0\in \partial f(x)$,
$0\in \partial f(y)$, then $tx+(1-t)y$ is a minimiser for
$t \in [0,1]$ which contradicts strictness.